# Данные не полностью записываются в БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть поле типа `varchar(255)`. В него PHP скриптом пишутся ФИАС идентификаторы вида `"2bbcf2f9-e48a-48dd-9838-b4a27dedffce"`. Периодически (не всегда) возникает проблема, что MySQL обрезает строку идентификатора до первой буквы или тире и записывает только эту часть. То есть вместо `"2bbcf2f9-e48a-48dd-9838-b4a27dedffce"` запишется только цифра `2`. При повторном выполнении запроса (скриптом, вручную) данные записываются полностью.

В чем может быть проблема?

*MySQL ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.22-72.0, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper*.

Пример проблемного запроса: http://pastebin.com/nPVXVdgT

Код скрипта: http://pastebin.com/tt0k2mLh, запись в бд происходит на 448 строке, обратите внимание, операция обернута в транзакцию. В качестве `$operator_db` используется модуль php mysqli

Comment: Имеет смысл добавить в вопрос PHP-код, в котором вы записываете данные.

Comment: думаю, что в базу пишутся уже "неверные данные". А по ходу получения данных от пользователя и до ее записи в базу происходит преобразование. Например, вместо конкатенации точкой, используется плюс. Вот и преобразуется в число.

Comment: Это не может быть php код, исключено, ведь большую часть запросов все пишется должным образом? И при прогоне того же скрипта на проблемных данных данные тоже записываются полностью? В mysql включено логирование запросов, пример проблемного запроса: http://pastebin.com/nPVXVdgT. Логи php скрипта это подтверждают - для формирования запроса передается полная строчка.

Comment: а повтороное выполнение проблемного запроса нормально сохраняет данные?

Comment: да, сохраняет нормально

Comment: меня в указанном запросе смущает то, что время передается как строка. Не хорошо это. 

без текста скрипта сложно судить. Вряд ли MySQL битый.

Comment: Код скрипта: http://pastebin.com/tt0k2mLh, запись происходит на 448 строчке, обратите внимание, операция обернута в транзакцию.

Comment: все запросы генерируются ручками. Если в каком то с полей появится кавычка - будет очень весело. А если будет две - то запрос может стать совсем другим.

Comment: Согласен, качество кода оставляет желать лучшего, скрипт отдал как есть, времени переделывать нет, а вот указанная ошибка доставляет много хлопот, поэтому все мое внимание пока на нее.

Comment: обрезаются оба идентификатора? или только 1-ый или 2-ой? данные, идущие после проблемных строк сохраняются нормально?

попробуйте делать `var_dump($zakaz)` и `echo $query` в файл перед выполнением запроса - может что-нть прояснится

Comment: Код точно актуальный? В 442 строке, например, значение `act_id` всегда `'NULL'`, а в вашем проблемном запросе пустая строка.

Comment: Да, актуальный. Запрос логировался на стороне mysql, а не php, возможно, поэтому.